# Add class to element when second div has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Li element (dropdown) that gets an Active class when parent div (button) is clicked. When this element have this class I want to give another div the same class. When the  li element (dropdown) is clicked again the active class is removed, I then want to remove the active class on the second div aswell.

What I got so far:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

This works a bit on the way in console- it gives my second div the correct class. It doesnt work live though, I guess I cant just call it on pageload? It also doesnt remove the class.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code that handles the clicking. As you surmised, it is not useful to set it once at page load time :)

Comment: Thats a lot of code.. but its in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jerryskate/doxdmxmL/15/

Comment: then simplify the code

Comment: please add more code.. we need the full html also.. the code which you are calling is on dom ready...that should be called on "div (button) click" also the fiddle link isn't helping.. the code (mentioned above) is not even there !

Comment: I do not see the `active` class appearing on your sample's `LI` elements. Can you confirm which part of the code is supposed to set that class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
       $("#site-overlay").addClass("active");
    } else {
       $("#site-overlay").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like something that would work! Im getting function undefined trying this on console though? @Nicola Avancini

Answer (score 0):

Your current example is not setting the `active` class on the `LI` elements, so nothing happens, but it should work something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.megamenu > li').on('click', function () {
        $("#site-overlay").toggleClass("active", $(this).hasClass('active'));
    });
});
```

`toggleClass` can take a second boolean parameter that controls turning on/off the class based on a true/false value.

Note: I hacked the following JSFiddle just to show something working (the clicking just toggles the site-overlay state for now):

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/doxdmxmL/16/

Comment: Yes it doesn work correct. i couldnt make the fiddle work as the live example. You can see it here: shop.xeptor.se. I dont want it to toggle on click, becasue the overlay should show when the submenu is active. In your example. you click on menuitem one - overlay shows. If you then click on next menuitem, it hides the overlay again even though the submenu shows. @TrueBlueAussie